# Extjs suspendEvent on radio button

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I am using Extjs4.2.2.

For a radiogroup I have a change listener in controller. I am changing radio selection several times progmatically but I don't want change events to fire in some cases. So I used suspendEvents before changing the selection as follows:

```
radio.suspendEvents();
//radio.suspendEvent('change');
radio.setValue({communication: 1}); // where communications is the name of radios
```

However this did not help and a change event is still fired.

How to stop that.

Comment: Do you have your `change` event listener configured on whole `radiogroup` or single `radio` component?

Answer (score 1):

The suspendEvent event bug is there for comboboxes too. Here are the bug reports:

- http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?171525-suspendEvents-did-not-affect-to-Ext.app.Controller.control
- http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?232919-ComboBox-suspendEvents-doesn-t-work

I found a solution that fixes it for comboboxes. Maybe the solution works for radios too. It works in Ext JS 4.2.1. Maybe other versions too.

```
radio.suspendCheckChange++;
radio.setValue({communication: 1});
radio.suspendCheckChange--;
```